# Нужен ли к тире какой-то дополнительный знак?

Tags: пунктуация

> Моё общение с ними пришлось на самое красивое время, которое есть у
>   мальчишек – когда они мечтают.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1) Моё общение с ними пришлось на самое красивое **время**, (2) которое есть у мальчишек, – (3) когда они мечтают.

Тире обозначает бессоюзную связь между предложениями 1 и 3 (какое именно время?), а предложение 2 относится к предложению 3 и выделяется запятыми.